# What's the inverse fourier transform for this function

Tags: fourier-transform

I need some help understanding how to proceed for the inverse tranform of the following function:

$X(f)=\frac{1}{2} sinc(f-f_0)+\frac{1}{2} sinc(f+f_0)$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks very straightforward if you have a table of Fourier Transforms under the eyes. What have you tried yet ?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(t)\cos(2 \pi f_0t) \Longleftrightarrow 
\frac{1}{2}[F(f - f_0) + F(f + f_0)]$$

$$\text{rect}(t) \Longleftrightarrow \text{sinc} (f)$$